# Merging rows of binary data based on columns using ddply

Tags: r, sum, plyr

I have the following dataframe for which I want merge together binary values from an amount of rows.

```
df =data.frame(ID=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)), nr=c(rep("2",5),rep("3",5)), replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))

eg:

# ID nr X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# A  2  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
# A  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
# A  2  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   1
# A  2  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0   1
# A  2  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
# B  3  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1   1
# B  3  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
# B  3  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   1
# B  3  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   1
# B  3  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
```

Now I want to merge rows for the first 2 columns in this case:

```
df2 = ddply(df, c(1:2), summarise, numcolwise(sum,c(3:12)))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in vector(type, length) : 
   vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'closure'.
```

Also I would want that anything higher than 1 to be reset to 1 to keep it binary, but since I couldn't get past the error I haven't tried it yet.

I know variations of this question have been asked before but I haven't found it like this before. Keep in mind that I want to use column indices because I'm working with large data.

Comment: Are you looking for the equivalent of `aggregate(. ~ ID + nr, df, sum)` but in "plyr"?

Comment: Yes. I guess this could work too although my data is quite large.

Comment: Try `ddply(df, c(1:2), colwise(sum, c(3:12)))`. Or: `ddply(df, c(1:2), numcolwise(sum))`. See `?summarize` and the `...` argument: "further arguments of the form var = value". In your attempt, you provide a function (`numcolwise`) as argument. Hence the error.

Comment: Both `aggregate` and `ddply` will be equally slow probably.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks that works! I guess I didn't really understand the summarize function or why it was(n't) needed in this case.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I'd still place my bet on aggregate if it's between these two options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is quite large (as mentioned in comments), forget about `plyr`, try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = list(ID, nr)]

##    ID nr X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
## 1:  A  2  2  3  5  2  5  2  1  3  4   1
## 2:  B  3  3  3  4  1  3  2  3  2  1   4
```

Or if you want to stick with the `plyr` family, move on to the next generation: `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, nr) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))

# Source: local data table [2 x 12]
# Groups: ID
# 
#   ID nr X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
# 1  A  2  2  3  5  2  5  2  1  3  4   1
# 2  B  3  3  3  4  1  3  2  3  2  1   4
```